# Using Sequelize like Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js, sequelize.js

I am new to using Nodejs and sequelize, coming from Rails. I love sequelize and how it's very similar to ActiveRecord. The one thing I do miss though is Rails console where I can do my AR queries to make sure my logic is correct or I am getting the right data before putting it into my code base. This is especially great for testing migrations and associations.

Is there something similar for sequelize where I can test my queries without having to run the server and throwing it into my controllers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can run your code in node.js console, just start nodejs.exe (or whatever OS you are using) in your command line and write code in it